# Spring Boot with Tomcat embedded under windows server 2008 R2 doesn't work

Tags: spring, gradle, spring-boot, tomcat8

Folks, I have a spring-boot app **running** locally with gradle build tool, with custom: `server:
  servlet-path: /own/api
  port: 8989` without any problem. However it doesn't work in WindowServer 2008-R2, I just get in log:

```
DispatcherServlet with name dispatcherServlet processing GET request for [/own/api]

Looking up handler method for path [/own/api]
```

Maybe WindowsServer would require something extra configuration, but not sure, i guess to deploy a spring boot application with tomcat embedded wouldn't have any trouble:

```
java -jar myfile.jar
```

Under AdvancedREST client tool I just get:

> http://SERVER-API:8989/own/api

```
{
"timestamp": "2016-07-05T21:13:25.884+0000"
"status": 404
"error": "Not Found"
"message": "/own/api"
"path": "/own/api"
}
```

As aforementioned, locally it works fine but **not** in windows server 2008R2. I was wondering if there was a manager in tomcat embedded, just to figure out what basePath would be, because I tried with:

```
http://SERVER-IP:8989/myfile/own/api //but didn't work either.
```

Any help I'd really appreciate.

Comment: Check your version of Java.

Comment: Where in your code have you defined the "own/api" endpoint?

Comment: Can you share the log output from starting your app on Windows?

Comment: this is part of the log on starting..

Comment: [PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.java:90] Found key 'sun.boot.class.path' in [systemProperties] with type [String] and value C:\Prog..\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Prog..\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Prog..\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\jre\lib\sunrsasign.jar;C:\Prog..\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Prog..\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Prog..\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Prog..\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Prog..\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\jre\classes'

Comment: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8181"]
Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8181"]
Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
[TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:162] Tomcat started on port(s): 8181 (http)
[MutablePropertySources.java:97] Adding [server.ports] PropertySource with highest search precedence
[StartupInfoLogger.java:57] Started Main in 67.238 seconds (JVM running for 68.815)

Comment: your log tells the app uses port 8181 and not 8989 as you've written.

Answer (score 0):

Folks, I found the solution which is adding a slash character to the end of the URL.

```
http://server:port/own/api/     instead of  http://server:port/own/api
```

I've faced with this issue in the past in other scenarios with Tomcat.